# Background slideshow with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, slider

How can I make a background slideshow with JQuery?

Comment: Please show the slider code, and if possible put that code snippet into a jsFiddle because your website will most likely not remain the same for future people who view this question.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't make the website and I'm kinda lost looking at the code but I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your plugin is no longer recognizing if the browser is chrome, I would check the vendor to see if there is a new version.  If there is not a new version and this splash page is all the plugin is used for then I would recommend using jQuery Cycle (not a wordpress specific plugin) instead with CSS to make the images fullscreen.

For the js plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/
For the CSS I would go here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't figure out what the problem was so I made another one useing JQuery Cycle. Thanks again!